# Is there an HTTP option to post data and don't ask for response?

Tags: http, post, protocols, httpresponse

I want to post data, but I don't need the response from the server, is there any way I can tell this to the server?

Comment: Do you have control over the server-side post handler? Simply have it not output anything. Otherwise, not really. Even a "null" response from a server has various headers output, even if the body of the response is empty.

Comment: What would trigger the post? Javascript? Server-side code?

Comment: @David If by trigger the post you mean, what sends the post data to the server, it is a C program. If you mean what handles the post data, it's normal server PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don’t think this is possible. But you can keep the response to a minimum like:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 
‍
```

That’s only 17 bytes: 15 bytes for the [status line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1) (`HTTP/1.1`, space, [`204` status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.2.5), space, no [reason phrase](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6.1.1) and the terminating CRLF) plus two bytes for the CRLF between the header and the non-existing message body.

Comment: The above isn't actually legal without a Content-Length or a Connection:close. HTTP/204 is the "no content" response.

Comment: @EricLaw -MSFT-: This *is* legal. You can build this with the ABNF production rules (start with [Response](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-6)). Additionally: “The action performed by the POST method might not result in a resource that can be identified by a URI. In this case, either 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) is the appropriate response status, depending on whether or not the response includes an entity that describes the result.” Although a 204 response is more appropriate, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You could add either a querystring or form value (e.g., output="false") that, if found, stops anything from being output. It's up to you to parse and interpret that in your PHP.